# How to update a CRM 2011 Entity using LINQ in a Plugin?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We are able to create new entities without any issues, but updating an existing entity in a plugin this does not appear to be working.  This is for CRM 2011.

```cs
var crmContext = new CustomCrmContext(service);

var contact = crmContext.Contact.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == targetEntity.Id);

contact.new_CustomField = "Updated";

crmContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to mark the object as modified in order to get it submitted to the server.
See [OrganizationServiceContext.UpdateObject (Entity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.updateobject.aspx)

You should add
`crmContext.UpdateObject(contact);` before `crmContext.SaveChanges();`

Comment: <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request.</Message>

Comment: Above is what I get when I do an UpdateObject.  Again, I can add a new record without any issue.  It is just updating an existing object that doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please describe how you registered your plugin? Is it registered for update of contact? The SaveChangesException has a property "Results" - which items are included?

Comment: I had the same problem. After I added context.UpdateObject(entity) before context.SaveChanges() it worked.

Comment: I have the same results that @Chad, any suggestions?

Comment: @MarcoMedrano check the Exception. Is there any other plugin which is triggered or is the same plugin triggered through the update

Comment: Hi @ccellar, In my case it does not do anything, I mean I call UpdateObject and also SaveChanges, but plainly does not do anything.

Comment: @MarcoMedrano maybe it would be better if you could create a new question and post some code

Comment: @ccellar you right, I would include even the Plugin messages that I am using to replicate the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

No need to download the whole Contact record if you already have the Id and you just need to update a field or two.  You also don't need the OrganizationServiceContext - just the Service.  Try something like:

```cs
var c = new contact() {
  Id = targetEntity.Id,
  new_CustomField = "Updated"
}

service.Update(c);
```

This will save the roundtrip of querying for the contact first.

Comment: If you have previously fetched the entity from a OrganizationServiceContext, and you then query for it again. Won't it be already be cached in the context, i.e. no roundtrip will be performed?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is fine, just create the new object or list and loop the list in the linq and update:

```cs
using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service)){
var foo = crm.nmipcs_productpriceitemSet
    .Where(ppis => ppis.nmipcs_Account.Id == account.Id).ToList();

foreach (var nmipcsProductpriceitem in foo){
    var f = new nmipcs_productpriceitem
    {
    Id = nmipcsProductpriceitem.Id                 
    ,
    nmipcs_PriceSalesChannel = (decimal) 9.99
    };

    service.Update(f);
}
    }
```