# "EntityState must be set to null, Created (for Create message) or Changed (for Update message)" when attempting to update an entity in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am using the following code to update an entity.

```
Service.Update(_policy);
```

where policy is a class generated using CrmSvcUtil.exe

```
public partial class new_policy : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

I retrieve the policies using LINQ, then update one attribute (an EntityReference) and then attempt the update

When this code runs I get the following error message:

> EntityState must be set to null, Created (for Create message) or
>   Changed (for Update message)

There are other entities generated in the same way that I can update.

I tried

```
_policy.EntityState = EntityState.Changed
```

but then I get a message saying

> The entity is read-only and the 'EntityState' property cannot be
>   modified. Use the context to update the entity instead.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to tell your `crmContext` (use appropriate name) what to do with the changes.

> You should add crmContext.UpdateObject(contact); before crmContext.SaveChanges();

See also [How to update a CRM 2011 Entity using LINQ in a Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074833/how-to-update-a-crm-2011-entity-using-linq-in-a-plugin/5077786#5077786)

Answer (score 12):

To avoid the problem you can simply use update-helper-objects instead of using the retrieved record:

```
var policyUpdater = new Policy { Id = _policy.Id, FieldToUpdate = "newValue" };
service.Update(policyUpdater);
```

Note: Properties of the update-helper-object that aren't set are simply ignored. The update won't set the corresponding record fields to null

Comment: Thank you, this helped me today!

Comment: Best answer here easily because 1) it is very straightforward and 2) it doesn't assume that the query went for only the relevant columns (otherwise you will be resubmitting columns that aren't changing, causing a nightmare if you are trying to read the audit history).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. I switched from using

```
context.Update(object)
```

to

```
context.UpdateObject(object)
```

and it worked.

Comment: I think you meant that you switched from using service.Update(object) to context.UpdateObject(object)

Comment: TimPartridge: In CRM 2011 the context also has an `Update` method

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
recordToUpdate.EntityState = EntityState.Changed;
```

(recordToUpdate is an Entity to be updated)

Comment: The EntityState is read only (maybe new in 2013). You should use the context to updater the state instead.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an issue with my linq query that was retrieving the entity in the first place. When I replaced this with a query expression it worked okay.

Time to brush up on my linq!

Comment: I also wanted to use LINQ, even switched my existing QueryExpressions to it, only to find out it doesn't work. This post is the only explanation I've found so far which says retrieving an entity via LINQ and then updating it is not allowed by design. LINQ is designed only for querying.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/682a7be2-1c07-497e-8f58-cea55c298062/

Comment: Just a friendly advise, be careful with LINQ, it seems that the query is executed each time you're using the object you're fetching and not storing it in memory if you're not careful. (necroposting deluxe but it might help someone)