# JSON error "EntityState must be set to null, Created (for Create message) or Changed (for Update message)"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am creating an entity record by sending a REST call using `XrmSvcToolkit.createRecord()` method, but the `JSON` returned is accompanied with this error

> EntityState must be set to null, Created (for Create message) or
>   Changed (for Update message)

It's a simple REST call but I don't have any idea about this error. I googled it and found few hits but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

I had been getting the same error as you. In my scenario I had a pluggin that was triggered on creation of my record and it was in Post Operation. So afeter some search I found out that I had to change the EntityStatus of my context entity. I did that as follow and it worked pretty good!

EntityContext.EntityState = EntityState.Changed;

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating it, it looks like the EntityState needs to be set to `Created`.

### Edit

Looks like this is an error when using the LINQ To CRM ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187978/entitystate-must-be-set-to-null-created-for-create-message-or-changed-for-u)).  My guess is that you have a plugin that is being triggered on your rest create, that is causing the exception that you are seeing.

Comment: Daryl, How can I do it from client side. Actually I am creating it through REST.

Comment: It does not give me the GUID, where would I set the EntitState and how??